# How to add a small bit of context in a grammar?

Tags: lark-parser

I am tasked to parse (and transform) a code of a computer language, that has a slight quirk in its rules, at least I see it this way. To be exact, the compiler treats new lines (as well as semicolons) as *statement separators*, but other than that (e.g. inside the statement) it treats them as *spacers* (whitespace).

As an example, this code:

```
try
    local x = 5 / 0
catch (i)
    print(i + "\n")
```

is proved to be equivalent to this:

```
try local x = 5 / 0 catch (i) print(i + "\n")
```

I don't see how I can express such a rule in EBNF, or specifically in Lark EBNF dialect. I mean in a sensible way. I probably could define all possible newline positions inside all statements, but it would be cumbersome and error-prone.

I wish to find a way to treat newlines contextually. Is there a proven method for this, preferably within Python/Lark domain? If I have to modify the parser for that purpose, then where should I start?

Or if I misunderstood something in this language in particular or in machine language parsing in general, or my statement of the problem is wrong, I'd also be happy to get educated.

(As you may guess, the language in question has a well proven implementation, but no officially defined grammar. Also, it is Squirrel, for all that it matters.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant quote from the "specification" is this:

> A squirrel program is a simple sequence of statements.:
>
> `stats := stat [';'|'\n'] stats`
>
> [...] Statements can be separated with a new line or ‘;’ (or with the keywords `case` or `default` if inside a switch/case statement), both symbols are not required if the statement is followed by ‘}’.

These are relatively complex rules and in their totality not context free if newlines can also be ignored everywhere else. Note however that in my understanding the text implies that `;` or `\n` are required when no of the other cases apply. That would make your example illegal. That probably means that the BNF as written is correct, e.g. both `;` and `\n` are optionally everywhere. In that case you can (for lark) just put an `%ignore "\n"` statement and it *should* work fine.

Also, lark should not complain if you both ignore the `\n` and use it in a rule: Where useful it will match it in a rule, otherwise it will just ignore it. Note however that this breaks if you use a Terminal that includes the `\n` (e.g. `WS` or `/\s/`). Just have `\n` as an extra case.

(For the future: You will probably get faster response for lark questions if you ask over on [gitter](https://gitter.im/lark-parser/Lobby) or at least put a link to SO there.)

Comment: “Also, lark should not complain if you both ignore the \n and use it in a rule: Where useful it will match it in a rule, otherwise it will just ignore it” − this looks like the exact feature I need in my case. Great thanks! I'll try it out ASAP and tell you how it works.